# Does the Facebook or AdMob SDK use cryptography?

Tags: cordova, cryptography, admob, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm developing a mobile application with Cordova and the Ionic framework. I'm also using the Cordova Facebook plugin and Cordova AdMobPro plugin which are written in java and objective c. I don't know java and objective c programming language. 
While submitting the application on iTunes Connect it asks me if my application is using cryptography or not. Do any of these SDKs or plugins use cryptography?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You will have to answer yes to the "Does this application use the advertising identifier" question though because you're using AdMob.

Comment: Thanks @daniel for the answer. Are you sure?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about @Daniel Storm answer

Facebook have their own crypto library, named Conceal https://facebook.github.io/conceal/

And according to their page, this is used to store the images into the SD into android devices, so, probably, the answer to the question title is YES.

But, quoting again their page

> Conceal doesn't implement any crypto, but instead, it uses specific
>   cryptographics algorithms from OpenSSL.

They are only cryptographics algorithms, not crypto *per se*, so probably the answer to Apple Question about cryptography usage is NOT